# How to remove %20 from Uri in c#?

Tags: c#, uri

I want to remove `%20` from file name but it should be in Uri format.

```
Dictionary<string, Uri> urilist = new Dictionary<string, Uri>();
  string fileName="test data.txt";

Uri partUriDocument;
partUriDocument = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));

urilist.Add(fileName, partUriDocument);
```

partUriDocument contains `test%20data.txt`.

How to make it `test data.txt`.

Comment: Why would you want to? That's a valid URL and `test data.txt` is not.

Comment: Agree with DavidG, misread your code first time. %20 is a space representation in Uri. So it is better to keep it the way it is.

Answer (score 7):

> partUriDocument contains test%20data.txt.
>   How to make it test data.txt.

You can properly decode it using

```
var decodedFileName = WebUtility.UrlDecode(fileName); // returns "test data.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called decoding. It's the same mecanic you're using when you go from

```
string str = "123"; //String
int number = Int.Parse(str) // Decode string into a number
```

> You **encode** your string in an uri, you **decode** your uri in a string

Use `Uri.Parse`

```
var str = Uri.Parse(Uri);
```

Comment: Be aware the question is tagged with **C#**. There is no `Uri.parse(input)` in C#

Comment: @DavidG DE-Edited :D Dunno why i wrote that, for getting right just below

Comment: @nozzleman you're right. I was thinking for asp.net. And btw, even in .NET, this method is deprecated https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.uri.parse(v=vs.110).aspx . Actually learned something fromt his msitake hey

Comment: Yeah, `Url.parse` doesn't exist in the .Net Framework either

Comment: @DavidG Uri.Parse() exist. It is depecrated tho.

Comment: You used a lower case `p` which would be a different method.

Comment: @DavidG Man. I should really reread myself sometimes. I'm editing this aswell